# Feed subscription of a Page

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to get notifications when a new feed has landed on a designated page (by page id). After what I understand, the Realtime-update og Graph API should be able to do this trick according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.4.

So I want to add a new subscription, which I try to do with the following code:

```
dynamic result = client.Post(urlPath, new
        {
            @object = "page",
            callback_url = callbackUrl,
            fields = "feed",
            verify_token = "654321",
            access_token = accessToken
        });
        return result;
```

But when I try to run this, I'm getting the following error code:

> (OAuthException - #2200) (#2200) callback verification failed: Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT"

What do I miss?
The callback url is https://127.0.0.1:8989/ and I have a TcpListener running on the port, which does not seem to get any response/request incoming...

The application is a C# console application, so no fancy asp.net stuff or something. I'm using the Facebook .net SDK.

Should I FacebookClient.VerifyPostSubscription() or anything else that I missed out?? Maybe the SDK wraps a handle?

So the answer I'm looking for is:
- How do I create/add a subscription for feeds of a facebook page, using the .net SDK on a windows console project??

UPDATE:
I changed the loopback with a domain name, that I the NAT to my target machine, and now I actually get some encrypted data on my TcpListener!
So, the question now is, how do I respond correctly to this received respons, only by using a Tcp Client??

Comment: Just for anyone else, having same issue as I ran into. The solution is to make sure your are public available, so FB can reach the callback URL you set, and get the hub.mode, hub.challenge, hub.verify_token from the GET request you receive, and send a response according to the doc. Callback URL can both be https or http.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How you have to respond is exactly outlined in the docs you linked:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.4#setupget

It's not really clear what you mean with "TCP listener". You need to have some logic why can send HTTP responses to the Facebook servers, otherwise your service will be disregarded after some time, meaning no updates will be send.

Typically, this is implemented as a script/application in a web/application server.

Please note: The "C# SDK" is a third-party SDK and not officially supported by FB.

Comment: Thanks for your contribute. By Tcp listener I mean, that I have a TCP Client (socket) running, waiting for any incoming request/response. And I get that now, but since it's encrypted I need to decrypt it and send a 200 OK back, I guess? Is it possible to set a 'http' callback url instead of a 'https'??

Comment: And by the way, if I knew what to do by reading the doc that I linked, I wouldn't even post this....

Comment: It's all in the docs. What exactly is unclear? *"The HTTP request will contain an X-Hub-Signature header which contains the SHA1 signature of the request payload, using the app secret as the key, and prefixed with sha1=. Your callback endpoint can verify this signature to validate the integrity and origin of the payload"*

Comment: Problem is that I'm getting this error: (OAuthException - #2200) (#2200) callback verification failed: Operation timed out after 6001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Comment: As I said, you have to send a proper HTTP response back. Thus the timeout error. And, you have to handle the verify request correctly, before FB sends you any updates. Again, it's all in the docs.

Comment: Tobi, as I said, if I knew how to do, after reading the doc, I wouldn't even ask this question... So any help in HOW I can accomplish would be great, maybe even an example of how to get on. But thanks anyways.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a programming service. Google how to send HTTP responses with a C# console application would be a start...